# LayoutTransition animation on ExpandableListview does not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-animation, expandablelistview

I want to apply a simple rotationX animation when a group expands/collapses on an ExpandableListView. The code below works in first two expands but after two/three/five times does not play the defined animation. The strange thing is that the first time that I expand /collapse it works perfect!

```
ExpandableListview exp = new ExpandableListview(context);
// set adapter code 
LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();

Animator appearAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "rotationX", 90f,0f).setDuration(transition.getDuration(LayoutTransition.APPEARING));
transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, appearAnim); // I also tried first argument equals DISSAPEARING, CHANGING, etc


exp.setLayoutTransition(transition);
```

Any idea?? Is this approach totally wrong???

I have to notice at this point that this is not a duplicate! I am looking for a solution that will be approached with LayoutTransition class / methods.

Comment: Would you please post your layout file?

Comment: I think that it is not necessary to post the layout file. It is complicated and it is a normal layout file. I think that maybe I have to do something inside the adapter getView and getGroupView bodies...

Comment: What you have posted is not enough information to solve this problem.  In order to test a solution I would have to create my own layout file which would most likely be different from yours.

Comment: have you tried setting adding this to your layout file: `android:cacheColorHint="@null"`?

Comment: @itsben my layout is pretty complicated. And each group of ExpandableListview shows custom objects and contains another ExpandableListviews. So lets go back to the question : is the LayoutTransition approach wrong?

Comment: @Chris I tried the cacheColorHint method, but it seems the same. The problem still exists...

Comment: I would love to solve this one but I don't think I have enough to go on. I like to test my solutions before I post the answer. That way I know it works and you get the complete source code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some awesome sample which may help you to do animation on  expands/collapses on an ExpandableListView, In the [android-flip](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip) library that uses OpenGL for rendering animation ,if the minimum supported Android version for the app was 4.0  we can use standard Android SDK methods instead of OpenGL: View.setRotationX(), View.setScaleX(), etc. When hardware acceleration is enabled (and it is enabled by default if your target API level is >=14), these methods work quite efficiently using the device GPU.

You can use this  **[FoldableLayout](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout)** to implement folding animation for  expands/collapses on an ExpandableListView.

[image]

> Layout implementation in FoldableLayout:
>
> The first element to design was a layout that can fold in half. Our
>   approach was rather bold: the main layout (FoldableItemLayout) simply
>   contains a specialized layout (BaseLayout). During the animation, the
>   BaseLayout writes its contents to cache which is a specially created
>   Bitmap object based on the size of the original layout. view plaincopy
>   to clipboardprint?

```
class FoldableItemLayout extends FrameLayout {  
    @Override  
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {  
        Bitmap cacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
        mBaseLayout.setCacheCanvas(new Canvas(cacheBitmap));  
    }  
}  

class BaseLayout extends FrameLayout {  
    private Canvas mCacheCanvas;  

    private void setCacheCanvas(Canvas cacheCanvas) {  
        mCacheCanvas = cacheCanvas;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {  
        mCacheCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);  
        super.draw(mCacheCanvas);  
    }  
}
```

> In addition, we needed to use two extra Views (PartView) – for the
>   upper and lower image halves – which would display the corresponding
>   data in cache that represents the upper and lower halves of the image
>   (Bitmap). Both Views encompass the entire area of the main layout, but
>   display only the required parts. To achieve this effect, we calculated
>   the Bitmap limits – and in the onDraw() method we made Canvas draw the
>   required part via the drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst,
>   Paint paint) method.
>
> Then we managed to rotate these extra Views by setting the
>   setRotationX() method to the corresponding angle, achieving
>   independent rotation of the lower and upper parts of the images. To
>   pull this off, we add a new parameter for the FoldableItemLayout –
>   with the name FoldRotation.

Source: [How to Make a Paper Folding Animation in Android?](http://cases.azoft.com/creating-paper-folding-animation-in-android/)